# Swift tab bar view prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In VC1 (collection view) this is my prepareforsegue code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let segue = segue.destinationViewController as TabBarViewController


    var selectedIndex = self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as UICollectionViewCell)

    segue.selectedIndexPassing = selectedIndex?.row

}
```

When I get to VC2 (which is TabBarViewController), I println() selectedIndexPassing to see what returns. It returns correctly. And then, in VC2, I call this prepareforsegue to get to the actual view controller, or the first button in the tab bar:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var segue = segue.destinationViewController as PlayerFromRosterViewController
    segue.selectedIndexPassingForDisplay = 1
}
```

However, when I println() the `selectedIndexPassingForDisplay` in VC3 (PlayerFromRosterViewController) I get nil. Why isn't the variable passing from the Tab Bar navigation controller to VC3, AKA the first tab bar button view.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you checked whether the `prepareForSegue` in your TabBarController ever gets called?

It would never be called since the connection between a `UITabBarController` and its children view controllers isn't a storyboard segue. You should get a reference directly to the viewController from the `UITabBarController` by accessing its `viewControllers` collection at the index you want.

```
var tabBarController = segue.destination as UITabBarController
var destinationViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0] as YourViewController // or whatever tab index you're trying to access
destination.property = "some value"
```

Comment: gotcha... Can you show me how to do that really quick? Just a sample line of code would be great. Thanks!

Comment: unbelievably, I never would have thought it has no "real" segue. You saved me a second hour of attempts. Thanks.

Comment: You are the best :)