# Setting delegate to pass data from one tab to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I am using: XCode 8.2, Swift 3.0, iOS 10.2, iPhone 7.  I have a `Tab Bar Controller` with child `View Controllers`.

I am trying to send data from one view controller to another.

I've looked up how to do this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhqXUi1SF4s&t=66s) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307903/swift-tab-bar-view-prepareforsegue) but the first link isn't quite what I want since he is talking about Storyboard segues which doesn't appear to be the same type of segues used when moving between tabs.

The tab in which I am trying to send data:

```
protocol SendResultsDelegate {
    func sendResults(data: String)
}

class SendingVC {
    ....
    if delegate != nil {
        let data = // some string here
        delegate?.sendResults(data: data!)

    }
}
```

The tab in which I am trying to receive data and print it out:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController, SendResultsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTextField: UITextView!

    func sendResults(data: String) {
        resultsTextField.text = data
    }
}
```

And I am not sure if this is correct but...I also have a custom class attached to my Tab Bar Controller:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    let resultsIndex = 2

    if item == (self.tabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem])[resultsIndex] {
        let sendingVC : SendingVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SendingVC
        SendingVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it should be the `tabBar` function or the `prepare` function.  I'm basically trying: when the user clicks the results tab, that delegate is set and then passes through the `if` statement check on the `ResultsViewController` which can display the text field.  Of course, this fails to even compile/build and I am unsure where to go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself that as @Leo Feng said, I don't need to use the delegate pattern.  This answer proved helpful: [Passing data between tab viewed controllers in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651507/passing-data-between-tab-viewed-controllers-in-swift)

In my case, it was more like:

In the sending view controller:

```
let secondTab = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] as! ResultsViewController
secondTab.result_data = // my data here
```

In the receiving view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ResultsViewController: UIViewController, SendResultsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTextField: UITextView!

    var result_data : String? = nil

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if(result_data != nil) {
            // do stuff with result_data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your app has more than five tabs, this approach is not working, because the order of the tabs can be changed by the user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use delegate pattern here. If your tab is selected, your child view controller will load - which it means all the view cycle methods will be called immediately. You can set your data inside viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear of your child view controller.

Comment: Hm, okay.  So how do I pass data from one child View Controller to another?  Is it some type of global variable thing or do I also need to use `protocol` delegates?  Some examples would be very helpful.